# Linq Retrieve Entities using a Navigational Property

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Linq and EF.

I'm pretty new so I have some problem to retrieve entities using a Navigational Property (CmsContents).
I can return as an List but not as an IEnumerable.

- Could you tell me what is wrong in my code?
- Also do you know a better approach to retrieve Entities suing Navigational Properties?

Please provide me an example of code thanks!

```
    public IEnumerable<CmsGroupsType> GetMostPopularContents()
    {
        using (var context = new CmsConnectionStringEntityDataModel())
        {
            context.CmsGroupsTypes.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;
            var contents = context.CmsGroupsTypes.Single(g => g.GroupTypeId == 1).CmsContents;
            return contents.ToList();                                         
        }
    }
```

---

```
Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<WebProject.DataAccess.DatabaseModels.CmsContent>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<WebProject.DataAccess.DatabaseModels.CmsGroupsType>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generic types don't match: Your `.ToList()` is of `CmsContent`, but your return type is an `IEnumerable` of `CmsGroupsType`. I'm not sure if that was intentional, but changing the return type to `IEnumerable<CmsContent>` will make everything work.

Comment: Thanks I realize know my oversight on the returned type. Thanks for your help on this!

Answer (score -3):

Change your return type from `CmsGroupsType` to `WebProject.DataAccess.DatabaseModels.CmsContent`

Comment: @StriplingWorrior, yeah sorry I mean't from CmsGroupsType to CmsContent